How to Create Twilio "ReplyTo" for SMS Replies
Currently I am capturing replies from SMS messages that we send to customers and sending them to my email address.
What I want to do is create a “reply to” on these emails that will go directly back to the customers cell phone, presumably routed through the twilio system.  Is there a way to do this?  Maybe with the MessageSid ??
For example:

Send SMS message to customer with number "000-000-0000"
Customer replies to message.  Currently, this goes to my support email address (xxx@yyy.com)
I want to be able to reply to that email and it goes right to the same customer 000-000-0000.  Presumably this would be an email address something like [MessageSid]@twilio.com (EX: SMef6107899472a3026c573039c3686161@twilio.com) that would go to 000-000-0000.

If this is not possible, then I guess the customer can reply to the SMS message and it is routed to my cell # and we can rpely to each other there, but I did not want to use our personal cell numbers...
Thank you.
Dennis

I'm afraid Twilio doesn't provide such a service out-of-the-box. But it's definitely possible to build this integration on your own. For this, you could use an SendGrid Inbound Parse to listen to incoming email and forward them as text to the sender. I'm happy to scratch this out in a longer answer if that sounds like the solution to your problem.

So I currently am able to grab the reply from the person the message was sent to and send it to our email.  It would be nice to be able to reply to that email and have it go back to the cell phone number originally sent to.  That said, it would make sense to send their reply to our cell phone number so then we can see their cell phone number and reply right there like a normal text chain.  That how it would work right?

This is a bit confusing. Can you please update your question with all involved parties and name them (SMS Sender A, Email recipient B etc)

Done - please see above @iobert.

Thanks. As said in the first comment, twilio doesn't provide such a gateway/proxy. However, you could build this on your own with SendGrid

that's kinda what I was thinking on doing, but i could not find anything on how to relate it back to the customer's phone # when I replied to the email...  i think that the easiest thing would be to just have it work by when the customer replies to a message, it routes to a cell phone # instead of an email....  then we can reply from there.  Is that possible?

i did see this... https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy seems more complex than I need though...

Please note that Proxy Public Beta is not available to new customers. In either case, it's probably best to build a map from unique id to phone number in a local DB. Then you can resolve it every time the customer replies.

You could either parse the unique id from the message body or the local part of the email address

I do have access to the ID.  The issue is that I need to reply from an email, but I guess I could click a link, enter the msg, and it would go to them.  Not ideal but would work... sending a reply from a customer to my cell phone number would probably be easier...

The message sid could be the id as well. But I was thinking that you'd use a key or you DB that then points to the receiving number. It's basically up to your implementation

Right, I definitely can do that. I just can't reply to the email from Outlook, for example,and it goes directly to the customer cell phone number. The better solution is to simply have the reply. Go to a phone number instead of too an email address with the API.
